# Syntax error: unexpected end of file despite all statements are valid

Tags: php, html, syntax, syntax-error

I am using PHP to POST some value to this results page. I am trying to find out what kind of error I am missing. I have been starting at this with no luck. Can anyone see what I am missing syntax wise. As far as I can tell this SHOULD be running. Sadly all I currently get is a blank webpage.

```
<?php
if ($totalqty == 0){?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'>You did not order anything on the previous page!</td>
</tr>
<?php}
else{?>
<?php
if ($tireqty > 0){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $tireqty;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo TIREPRICE;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $tireqty;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php}

if ($oilqty > 0){ ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $oilqty;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo OILPRICE;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $oilqty;?></td>
</tr>
<?php}

if ($sparkqty > 0){ ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $sparkqty;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo SPARKPRICE;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $sparkqty;?></td>
</tr>
<?php}

if ($brakeqty > 0){ ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $brakeqty;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo BRAKEPRICE;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $brakeqty;?></td>
</tr>
<?php}
if($tuneup =='on'){ ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $tunup;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo TIREPRICE;?></td>
    <td style='text-align: right;'><?php echo $TUNEUP;?></td>
</tr>
<?php}
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not like the missing space between your braces and the `<?php` and `?>` tags. If you put a space in there it will work.

In order to make debugging future problems easier you should enable `display_errors` in your dev environment.

Comment: And yes: I was absolutely stunned about this one, as highlighting did not help here, I had a hard time to find it.

Comment: I added some of the spaces and had some results. My page is no longer blank however I still think I am doing something wrong with spaces. I have 0's ?'s and >'s that have popped up on the page. Is this still a spacing problem?  This is the string: 0){ ?> 0){ ?> 0){ ?> 0){ ?>

Comment: Finally found that my odd symbol problem came from echoing out constants.